# $\sum_{n=1}^{2016}\left\lfloor\frac{\sqrt n}{10}\right\rfloor$ in 2 minutes

Tags: summation, contest-math, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> Find
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^{2016}\left\lfloor\frac{\sqrt n}{10}\right\rfloor$$
>   where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$.

Apparently it is to be solved within 2 minutes! But I am completely lost on how to solve this.

Comment: Hint: $0+0+0+0+\cdots+0+1+1+1+1+\cdots+1+\cdots+2+2+2+2+\cdots$

Answer (score 7):

Just write it as:

$$\sum \left\lfloor{\frac{\sqrt{n}}{10}}\right\rfloor=\sum \left\lfloor \sqrt{\frac{n}{100}}\right\rfloor$$

Then just search for when you change integer, for example you get $3$ as soon as you are above $\sqrt{9}$ and under $\sqrt{16}$ where you will change for $4$, so for $n\geq 900$, $n<1600$.

Comment: Pretty smart idea. +1

Comment: Very clever! (+1)

Answer (score 5):

Look at the places where $f(n)=\frac{\sqrt n}{10}$ "trips" across integers:

- $f(n)=1$ when $n=100$, so $\lfloor f(n)\rfloor=0$ when $n<100$
- $f(n)=2$ when $n=400$, so $\lfloor f(n)\rfloor=1$ when $100\le n<400$ (300 numbers)
- Similarly, $\lfloor f(n)\rfloor=2$ when $400\le n<900$ (500 numbers)…
- $\lfloor f(n)\rfloor=3$ when $900\le n<1600$ (700 numbers)…
- $\lfloor f(n)\rfloor=4$ when $1600\le n<2017$ (417 numbers).

The answer is
$$300+2×500+3×700+4×417=5068$$

Comment: I got the same answer by the same approach.  It took me 1 minute 53 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that
$$
\frac{\sqrt{n}}{10} \le \frac{\sqrt{2016}}{10} < 5.
$$
That means, that for $1 \le n \le 2016$, we have
$$
\left\lfloor\frac{\sqrt{n}}{10} \right\rfloor \in \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4\}.
$$
You just have to count for how many $n$ it is each of $0, 1, 2, 3$, and $4$.